# Keep creating multiple child processes from the same parent

Tags: c, fork, child-process

I am trying to calculate the checksum of every binary file in the current directory using a separate process to improve performance. However, for some reason, my output is always unexpected.

How would I go around creating a separate process for each file? Should I have the entire forking process within a **while(pids[i] != -1)**?

```
file_cnt = number of .bin files in the current dir

pid_t pids[file_cnt];

for(i = 0; i < file_cnt; i++) 
{
    if((pids[i]=fork()) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error forking");
        return 0;
    }
    else if(pids[i]==0)
    {
        printf("Entering child \n");
        printf("%s ", filenames[i]);

        //reading file
        handle = open( filenames[i], O_RDONLY );

        //allocating memory
        buffer = malloc( BUFFER_SIZE );

        checksum = 0;

        do
        {
            //calculating checksum
        } while( length );

        printf( " -%d\n", checksum);
        printf("Exiting child \n");
    }
}
```

I have three files in the directory and my output comes out as:

```
There are 3 files:
Entering child 
whateve2.bin  -10540
Exiting child 
Entering child 
Entering child 
whatever.bin  -8399
Exiting child 
whatever3.bin  -34871
Exiting child 
Entering child 
whatever.bin  -8399
Exiting child 
vab@Vaibhav:~/CS330$ Entering child 
whatever3.bin  -34871
Exiting child 
Entering child 
whatever3.bin  -34871
Exiting child 
Entering child 
whatever3.bin  -34871
Exiting child
```

Comment: Your code prints `Exiting child` but it doesn't exit the child.

Comment: How would I know when the child is being exited? Isn't that at the end of the checksum?

Comment: If it's not killed by a signal, a process exits when it reaches the end of `main` or when it calls `exit()`.

Comment: So, I should add an exit() when I'm done calculating the checksum? But how would I ensure that I'm using a separate process for calculating checksum for each file in the directory?

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful.   always check (>=0) the returned value from open() to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: each child needs to `close()` the input file and pass the malloc'd memory to `free()` and call `exit(0);`

Comment: a checksum is not normally a signed value.  so it should be declared as `unsigned int checksum;`  and should be printed as "%8X".   why is there a '-' in front of the format specifier in the printf() statement?

Comment: @user3629249 I have all those error checking measures in my code. I just didn't put them in the question because I thought it was not relevant to the question. Thank you for being watchful though.

Comment: @user3629249 That's how I want the formatting to be: "filename" -filesize
My checksum is perfectly fine and I have used all the correct declarations for it. My only concern is regarding the multiprocessing.

Comment: *I am trying to calculate the checksum of every binary file* Given the variable name of 'checksum' (which implies a specific meaning which is not the size of the file. (the file size is easily obtained via the `stat()` function)  The posted code does not indicate how the 'checksum' field is being calculated, so I used the implied meaning of the word in my comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling `exit()` at the end of the `else` block for each child.  Because of that, the child will jump back to the `for` loop and perform the next iteration, calling `fork()` again.  If there are 3 files, the parent will fork 3 times, the child for file 1 will fork 2 times, and the child for file 2 will fork 1 time.

Right after the call to `printf("Exiting child \n");`, you need to call `exit(0)` so the child process quits.

Addressing your comment, the fact that you called `fork()` and checked that the return value is not < 0 ensures that a child process was created, and checking that the return value is 0 ensures that it's the child process that is running.

Remember that `fork()` returns twice if it succeeds: once to the parent with the pid of the child, and once to the child with 0.

Comment: The code seems to working flawlessly. Although, I have no way of checking whether or not different processes are involved or it's one big processes. But thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Vab You can verify that different processes are in use by printing the value of `getpid()` in the child section of the code.  Also, feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, you're not `exit()`ing at the end of the `else` block.

However I'd like to suggest an improvement: Since you're trying to implement parallel processing in order to gain performance on a quick task, how about using threads instead of `fork()`ing whole processes ?

Here's a code sample that illustrates what you could do:

```
// adapted from https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/
// compile with: gcc calc_checksum.c -o calc_checksum -lpthread

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* calc_checksum(void* pFileNameIdx)
{
    const int fileNameIdx = (int)pFileNameIdx;
    printf("Entering child \n");
    // filenames should be a global variable somewhere
    // or, better, just pass "&filenames[fileNameIdx]" instead of pFileNameIdx
    printf("%s ", filenames[fileNameIdx]);

    // reading file
    handle = open(filenames[fileNameIdx], O_RDONLY);

    // allocating memory
    buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

    int checksum = 0;

    do
    {
        // calculating checksum
    } while(length);

    printf( " -%d\n", checksum);
    printf("Exiting child \n");

    free(buffer);  // !! don't forget to free() the resources that you don't need anymore

    // exit the thread
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // initialization code ...
    file_cnt = number of .bin files in the current dir

    pthread_t threads[file_cnt];
    int retCode;

    for(i = 0; i < file_cnt; i++) 
    {
        retCode = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, calc_checksum, (void*)i);
        if (retCode){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", retCode);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

**NB**: regardless of the method (`fork()` or pthreads): do not forget to `free()` the memory that you have reserved with `malloc()`.

Comment: I haven't yet learned how threading works and how it is different from multi-processing. But once I learn that, I will definitely revisit your answer.

Comment: Here's an interesting article on the topic: http://www.geekride.com/fork-forking-vs-threading-thread-linux-kernel/